Partial SPL swap using raydium sdk
I have problem, because I have script, which is buying tokens and then selling it base on set criteria, but it's not working as I would like. Main problem is, whenever I do, script is selling entire balance of bought token. I would like him to sell only a part of the balance, e.g. 30%. Script is doing calculations how many it should pass to swap, but swap does not process or, if it does, sells the entire balance.
Here is part using swap function:
poolKeys: LiquidityPoolKeysV4,
ataIn: PublicKey,
ataOut: PublicKey,
tokenIn: Token,
tokenOut: Token,
amountIn: TokenAmount,
slippage: number,
wallet: Keypair,
direction: 'buy' | 'sell',
What should I do to pass calculated % of token for a swap? Should I change something in amountIn/Out? I'll add that I'm not familiar with web3 or programming, everything I do I try myself with things from the documentation or with the help of AI, so please be understanding

Hey can you attach the code to see what I can optimize? Thanks.
